# Pass javascript array to c# array/list using $.post without specifing datatype as json

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I have a model created in javascript as follows

```
function Vehicle() {
    this.type = 'Vehicle';
    this.data = {
        VehicleKey: null
    }
};
```

I have a similar model created in c# as follows

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string VehicleKey { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am building an array of `VehicleKeys` in javascript as follows

```
function GetVehicleDetails(inputarray) {

    var vehicleKeys = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < inputarray.length; i++) {
        var vehicleObject = new Vehicle();
        vehicleObject.data.VehicleKey = inputarray[i].VehicleKey ? inputarray[i].VehicleKey : null;
        vehicleKey.push(vehicleObject.data);
     }
    return vehicleKeys ;
}
```

I am calling the `$.post(url, data)` as follows

```
var objectToSend = GetVehicleDetails(selectedVehicles);

 var data = JSON.stringify({
     'vehicles': objectToSend
 });

 $.post(url, data)
     .done(function (result) {
          if (result) {
               download(result, 'VehicleReport.xlsx', { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
               console.log("Report created successfully");
           }
           else {
               console.log("Error creating report");
           }
      }).fail(function (error) {
               console.log("Error creating report.");
  });
```

The MVC Controller has a method to accept `Vehicles` with multiple `VehicleKeys` coming from javascript

```
public byte[] CreateVehicleReport(List<Vehicle> vehicles)
{
    //Generation of report and pass it back to javascript
}
```

Here I am able to submit the data in javascript as 10 and 11 for `Vehicles` but when it catches the c#, the count is coming as 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Specify the binding type(frombody)  c# side

Comment: Still the `vehicles` parameter shows the count as 0.

Comment: can you show your json value

Comment: `"{"vehicles":[{"VehicleKey":"10"},{"VehicleKey":"11"}]}"`.

Comment: you json format is wrong as well as  i think $.post is not posted Content-Type  as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post is not posted Content-Type json data so you need to use $.ajax

```
    function GetVehicleDetails(inputarray) {
          var vehicleKeys = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < inputarray.length; i++) {
               var vehicleObject = {};  // Set Object 
               vehicleObject.VehicleKey = inputarray[i].VehicleKey ? inputarray[i].VehicleKey : null;
                 vehicleKeys.push(vehicleObject);
                }
             return vehicleKeys;
          }

     var objectToSend = GetVehicleDetails(selectedVehicles);

       $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
                 url: url,
                  data: JSON.stringify(objectToSend),
                  contentType: "application/json",
                   dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('data: ' + data);
                    },
                }).done(function () {
                    if (result) {
                        console.log("Report created successfully");
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Error creating report");
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log("Error creating report.");
                });
```

## C# Method

```
[HttpPost("CreateVehicleReport")]
        public byte[] CreateVehicleReport([FromBody]List<Vehicle> vehicles)
        {
            return null;
            //Generation of report and pass it back to javascript
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar approach once but with ajax and it went like this:

fill your array directly with the properties inside your class as object { } make sure the names are exactly the same:

```
      function GetVehicleDetails(inputarray) {
        var data_Temp = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < inputarray.length; i++) {
        var _vehiclekey = inputarray[i].VehicleKey ? inputarray[i].VehicleKey : null;
        data_Temp.push({ VehicleKey : _vehiclekey });
        });
        return data_Temp;
       }

      var objectToSend = GetVehicleDetails(selectedVehicles);
      var JsonData = JSON.stringify({ vehicles: objectToSend });
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          url: "/controllerName/actionName", //in asp.net using mvc ActionResult
          datatype: 'json',
          data: JsonData,
          success: function (response) {
          },
          error: function (response) {
                 console.log(response);
           }
      });
```

And the ActionResult in the controller should look like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(List<Vehicle> vehicles)
    {
     //do whatever you want with the class data
    }
```

I don't know if this is helpful for you but this always works for me and i hope it helps.